# Child background attribute override the parent rounded corners background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I created a navigation bar using LinearLayout containing Clickable TextView's, for the containing LinearLayout I set a background shape XML for creating rounded corners, the problem is, when the user click on one of the tabs I set to the tab color backround, the rounded corners overwriting, the reason I set the rounded corners in the container and not in the tabs is because the right-left\left-right languages.

Before clicking

[image]

After clicking

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@color/registerButton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="A"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/registerButton">
</View>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/registerButton"
    android:text="B"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/registerButton">
</View>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@color/registerButton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="C"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/registerButton">
</View>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@color/registerButton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="D"/>
```

@drawable/rounded_corners

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/registerButton" />
    <corners android:radius="8dip"/>
    <padding android:color="@color/registerButton"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:top="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make a distinct selector for text view **A** where you need to set corner in your selector file:

```
  <corners
   android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="5dp">
  </corners>
```

change value of radiaus  as per your need

Comment: The problem is that when the user use left to right languages the layout for this tab will shown in the opposite direction, and if you give background to the controller it will be not difference for the user language.

Comment: could you please tell me what  do you mean by right-left\left-right languages . is it changing tab or anything else..

Comment: For example if we adding the rounded corners only for A TextView:  for English language the A tab will be the first (from left) and the rounded corners will be in the left of the tab, great, but for Hebrew or Arabic the A tab will be first (from right) and the rounded corners will be in the left side, wrong, I want them to be in the right side, this is the reason I give the rounded corners to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Create another xml file as below and save it in drawables folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#0066ff"/>  //new blue color, change the color code as you wish
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/registerButton" />
<corners android:radius="8dip"/>
<padding android:color="@color/registerButton"
    android:left="0dip"
    android:top="0dip"
    android:right="0dip"
    android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

in your java class file, handle onclick and set the background to newly created file.